# Context menu response time is slow in tree table

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I create one tree table with context menu. But context menu is slow sometime when I select the tree node. I have to wait for 2 seconds after I click on the selected tree node. The page is loading status. After that, I can see context menu.
This is not happen all the time. But I can see it many times. Does anybody know about this or encounter the same issue? Thanks.

```
<p:contextMenu id="testrundetailContextMenu" widgetVar="testrundetailContextMenu" beforeShow="return true;"  for="testrunDetailTreetable">
                    <p:menuitem value="Assign"  icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"  process="@this" update=":testrunassigneeDlg" />
    </p:contextMenu>
    <p:treeTable id="testrunDetailTreetable" value="#{testrunBean.testrunroot}" scrollable="true" selection="#{testrunBean.testrunselectedNode}" selectionMode="single" >
                    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{testrunBean.onNodeSelect}"  update=":mainForm:testrundetailContextMenu" oncomplete="PF('testrundetailContextMenu').show();" />
                    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{testrunBean.onNodeExpand}" />
                    <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{testrunBean.onNodeCollapse}" />
    </p:treeTable>
```

Comment: when I select node, I check content loadload time is 1.59s. It's 980ms sometime. Request send time is  0.27s on node select. When I use context menu, request time is 1.32s.

Comment: Debug…  debug…  debug…  read some generic (jsf related) articled on this and investigate.